# How to read images from a folder based on regex in Directory.GetFiles in C#?

Tags: file, directory

I need to load the images from a folder based on the name.

I am using regex to do the same, But instead of reading matching one it is reading all images inside the folder.

Below is my code

var maskImagePrefixName = "BCCasualCuffs_Back_Left_";

Regex reg = new Regex(@"^^(?!" + maskImagePrefixName + ").*");

var glowImagesByPrefix = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/GlowImages/"), "*.png").Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path)).ToList();

I have "BCCasualCuffs_Back_Left_glow.png" file inside directory and expected result is to read the same, but I am getting all the files.

Can Anyone assist where I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the below one, It was working perfectly

```
var glImg= Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/GlowImages/"), ""+ maskImagePrefixName + 
"*.png");
```